# How can i fix this npm / fsevents / node-gyp rebuild error in my yeoman generator for angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, node-gyp, fsevents

Here is the package.json:

> {
>       "name": "yeomanangular",
>       "version": "0.0.0",
>
> ```
> "dependencies": {
>     "express": "3.4.7"
> },
>
> "devDependencies": {
>     "grunt-express": "1.2.1",
>     "grunt": "0.4.1",
>     "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "0.4.1",
>     "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
>     "grunt-karma": "0.7.2",
>     "karma": "0.11.12",
>     "karma-requirejs": "0.2.1",
>     "karma-mocha": "0.1.1",
>     "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.1",
>     "karma-safari-launcher": "0.1.1",
>     "karma-firefox-launcher": "0.1.3",
>     "karma-chai": "0.0.2",
>     "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.6"
> } }
> ```

Here is the error:

> node-gyp rebuild
>
> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o In file included from
>   ../fsevents.cc:6: ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member
>   named 'New' in 'v8::String'
>       return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
>               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro
>   '_NAN_ERROR'
>
> ## define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))